# How do unter, hinter, etc. become unten, hinten, etc.?

Tags: declension

How do the prepositions *unter, hinter, and ober (not sure if ober should be included)* and the like become *unten, hinten, oben*?

For example:

> Ich stehe hinten rechts.
>
> Hinter dir ist ein Hund.
>
> Zieh' nach oben/unten zum Aktualisieren.

I am interested in the usage cases for these words **and** the linguistic reason(s) for the changes in ending.

Comment: Are you interested in when to use which word or what happened here linguistically?

Comment: Both.  I will add that to the question.  Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: For the usage part: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/difference-between-hinter-and-hinten/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between e.g. `unter` and `unten` is depending on what you are referring to and positions to each other. So the difference between `unter`and `unten` is the same as in `under your foot` and `down stairs`. So as a rule of the thumb I'd say, when ever you putting something in relation to something else, it should be really the preposition `unter`, `über`, `vor`, `hinter` etc.

If something is at a position not really related to something, than it's `oben`, `unten`, `vorn` or `hinten`. This also applies to positions inside e.g. a room: So you can say "Es befindet sich unten (im Keller)" means maybe something like "It's downstairs (inside the cellar)" whereas "Es ist hinter dem Keller" means "It's behind the cellar".

I have no clue how the grammatical thing is called ;)

Answer (score 5):

"unter" is a preposition (connected with a noun), "unten" is an adverb (indicating position).